# Why does the listview display the items incorrectly after I remove them in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have recently started programming with .NET MAUI. The elements are correctly removed in the C# list. However, after deleting the remaining elements are only partially displayed. That means that only e.g. the 4th element is displayed. For the other elements only an empty bar is displayed.

My code so far:
XAML:

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>


                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Source="logo.png"
                        WidthRequest="150"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"/>

                    <Label
                        TextColor="Black"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Text="TODO"
                        FontSize="35"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                        VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        Margin="23"/>


                </Grid>





                <Grid BackgroundColor="#24D4A3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ListView 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    RowHeight="100"
                    x:Name="listview">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                            <ViewCell >

                                    <Grid BackgroundColor="#24D4A3">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Button BackgroundColor="#DEABF5"
                                            Text="{Binding Title}"  
                                            Clicked="onNoteSelected"
                                            BorderWidth="2"
                                            TextColor="Black"
                                            FontSize="28"
                                            Margin="20"
                                            CornerRadius="100"
                                            WidthRequest="350"
                                            HeightRequest="70"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            VerticalOptions="Start"/>


                                        <Button
                                            BindingContext="{Binding Id}"
                                            Clicked="ToDoSolved" 
                                            BorderWidth="2"
                                            BorderColor="Black"
                                            BackgroundColor="White"
                                            WidthRequest="45"
                                            HeightRequest="45"
                                            CornerRadius="35" 
                                            Margin="0,0,260,0" 
                                            />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>

                    <ImageButton  
                                Clicked="Settings"
                                Source="settings.png"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                BorderColor="#2b3c3c" 
                                BorderWidth="0" 
                                BackgroundColor="#34A4EB" 
                                CornerRadius="35" 
                                HorizontalOptions="End" 
                                WidthRequest="70" 
                                HeightRequest="70" 
                                Margin="0,10, 10, 0" 
                                VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                        <ImageButton 
                                Clicked="CreateNote"
                                Source="add.png"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                BorderColor="#2b3c3c" 
                                BorderWidth="0" 
                                BackgroundColor="#34A4EB" 
                                CornerRadius="35" 
                                HorizontalOptions="End" 
                                WidthRequest="70" 
                                HeightRequest="70" 
                                Margin="0,0,10,10" 
                                Padding="2,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    { 

    private ObservableCollection<Note> notes = new ObservableCollection<Note>();
    public ObservableCollection<Note> Notes 
    {
        get { return notes; }
        set { notes = value; }
    }
    public MainPage()   
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        notes.Add(new Note(1, "My Note1", "I'm ugly"));
        notes.Add(new Note(2, "My Note2", "I'm short"));
        notes.Add(new Note(3, "My Note3", "I'm smart"));
        notes.Add(new Note(4, "My Note4", "I'm smart"));
        //notes.Add(new Note(6, "My Note6", "I'm smart"));
        //notes.Add(new Note(7, "My Note7", "I'm smart"));
        //notes.Add(new Note(8, "My Note8", "I'm smart"));
        //notes.Add(new Note(9, "My Note9", "I'm smart"));
        this.BindingContext= Notes;
        listview.ItemsSource= Notes;
        
    }

    private async void CreateNote(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//CreateNote");
    }

    private async void Settings(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Settings");
    }

 

    private void ToDoSolved(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button= (Button) sender ;
        
        var id = (int)button.BindingContext;
         
        var item = Notes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (item != null) 
        {
            Notes.Remove(item);
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
    
    }

    async void onNoteSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button= (Button) sender ;

        var id = (int)button.BindingContext;

        //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("NotePage" + id);
    }
}
```

I would be grateful for any help :)

Comment: please do not post duplicates

Comment: I thought its another question?

Comment: it is the same issue you were discussing with me in the comments of your previous question, and you accepted an answer on that question after those comments were made.  If the answer on that question did not solve your issue, you should add comments to the answer reflecting that

Comment: if you feel its a different issue, you can request to reopen it.  Please make clear in your question how this is different from the previous question.  And if you are asking specifically about a UI issue it helps to provide a screenshot illustrating the problem

Comment: Okay i updated my question so far